# Woocommerce - add CSS class to image in Shop Page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to add some custom class to img tags and after each img tag I want to add a span tag, so please let me know in which file I can find the shop page img tags.

For more details please have a look at below tag from the shop page:

```
<img width="300" height="222" src="http://testxone.com/tank-sanitizer/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/hand-sanitizer-300x222.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="">
```

Look at the screenshot for more details:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to add class to your img tags and append a span as you wanted.

**Add Class to img tag**

```
$('.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail').addClass('custom-class')
```

**Add span to you img tag**

```
$('.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail').append('<span class="my_span">My Custom Span</span>')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It could works but I am not looking for the solution using JS I want to know that particular file from where shop page image comes.